# Request the id used by my endpoints

Tags: rest

I have an endpoint called products and I can receive data for a product by id as follows:

```
/rest/products/12
```

However, I have a case where I wish to retrieve the product by barcode instead.

Would this make sense:

```
/rest/products?barcode=12378287738872
```

How might I design this?

Comment: I see no problems with your solution